# django-rosetta file is read only

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I am getting the following message at the top of my rosetta admin page:

```
File is read-only: download the file when done editing!
```

This never used to be there before, and I'm unsure at what point this started showing up since we've had a lot of dev changes recently and haven't had any text to translate. The outcome is that any translation changes we make do not take effect **in the admin section** after we click `save and translate next block` (ie. These changes do not *save* at all). Which kinda makes sense since the "file" is read only.

I've tried setting the `.po` and `.mo` file's permissions to 777 but the message remains. Even after resetting the server etc.

My question is: has anyone come across this issue? What file is it that is read-only? How do I set it to writeable? Or is something else at play here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue.

I was using Filezilla to change the permissions of the files. Whilst these changes appeared to have taken effect, they didn't actually make a difference. So I jumped into the terminal and used `chmod` to give the appropriate permissions to both the `django.mo` and `django.po` files (in this case I used `chmod g+w <filename>` to give group write access) and it worked.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the problem as each update will revert the permissions. Maybe we could use a [sticky bit](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/sticky-bit-on-directory-file/) but not sure it'll be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you need to change the permissions.
You need to restart the server also.